# onCollisionEnter2D not behaving as expected

Tags: unity, 2d, collision-detection

I have two game objects. They both have a Rigid Body 2D and a Box Collider 2D components.

One of them also has script component. Below is the full script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class Col : MonoBehaviour
{
void Start ()
{
}
void Update ()
{
}
void onCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
Debug.Log("collision detected");
}
}
```

When I start the project, go to the Scene view and drag one GameObject over another i don't get the Log message i am expecting to see.

What am i doing wrong here? Seems so simple.

Last pic is the size of the box colliders so you can see that they are correct size.

I've seem other very similar question and they are all in regards to unity5.0 (i am using 5.0 as well)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there some reason you want to delete this question? Did the answer below solve your problem? If not, why don't you post how you solved it as your own answer? Remember that this site isn't just for your personal use, the questions and answers are here to benefit everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel weird answering my own question but the problem is the

```
void onCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
```

It needs to be

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
```

(With the capital 'O').

Hope this help someone over there as it is rather easy to overlook for beginners

Comment: That's what my answer said, and you said it didn't help. Read my answer again. I said your method signature was incorrect.

Comment: i just caught the 2D part of your answer and i had that part already fixed before you posted it.  I had to dig elsewhere to catch the 'O' part.  Thanks for everything and sorry about our little scuffle, no hard feelings hopefully.

Comment: My fault, I only called out the `2D` change and not the capital `O` as well. Thanks for getting everything in order and modifying this question to be more clear.

Comment: All good, i suspected it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Collisions in the physics space (stuff using `onCollision`, not [`onTrigger`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnTriggerEnter2D.html)) need to have a [`Rigidbody2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html) attached to the objects. This `Rigidbody2D` component is what places the objects into the physics simulation and allows for the objects to collide with each other.

If you only want to know when the objects touch each other, and not simulate physics or collision responses, use [`onTriggerEnter2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnTriggerEnter2D.html) (Making sure to set your colliders to [triggers](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D-isTrigger.html)).

Also, you'll need to ensure your method signatures are correct:

```
void onCollisionEnter2D(Collision col)
```

is wrong. You want

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
```

Notice the `2D` type of collision is the correct way to implement this method, in addition to the capital `O` at the beginning.

I started a new scene. Added two 2D sprites. I added colliders to both. I then added a rigid body to one and attached a new script to the other. The script contained your code above for `OnCollisionEnter2D`. When I moved the rigidbody object over the other object, the debug text was printed.

You either need to start over because you've done something wrong or you need to reexamine your assumptions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22193/discussion-between-byte56-and-dust).